# How to filter matrix of char to get a smaller matrix with filtered results?

Tags: java, arrays, matrix

Given a matrix A:

```
[[C,c,c,c,a,a,b],
 [1,3,3,3,2,2,1]]
```

where the first row has characters A-Z and a-z, and the second row has numbers which represent how many times a given letter appears in the matrix, how could write code to take matrix A and transform it to matrix B where B is:

```
[[C,c,a,b],
 [1,3,2,1]]
```

in which first row shows no repeated letters, but in second row keeps the original times a letter repeats itself?

This is what I have tried so far:

```
for(i=0;i<matrixA.length;i++){
   if(matrixA[0][0] == matrixA[0][1]){  
   matrixB[0][0] = matrixA[0][0]
   matrixB[1][0] = matrixA[1][0]
   }
}
```

How can I solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I realized you can't simply remove the duplicates in your array, as then your `matrixB` would be:

```
[[C, c, a, b],
 [1, 3, 2]] //final '1' removed as it is a "duplicate" of the first
```

So I propose this method instead:

```
Object[][] matrixA = {
    {'C','c','c','c','a','a','b'},
    {1,3,3,3,2,2,1}};
ArrayList<Object> rowHolder = new ArrayList<>();

for(int i = 0; i < matrixA.length; i++){ //for each row
    int j;
    for(j = 0; j < matrixA[i].length-1; j++){ //for each element
        if(matrixA[i][j] != matrixA[i][j+1]) //keep element if next element is different
            rowHolder.add(matrixA[i][j]);
    }
    rowHolder.add(matrixA[i][j]); //add last element always (next element doesn't exist)
    matrixA[i] = rowHolder.toArray(); //convert rowHolder to row
    rowHolder.clear(); //reset for next row
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(matrixA[i]));
}
```

This gives the expected:

```
[C, c, a, b]
[1, 3, 2, 1]
```

---

The only ugliness here is having to use `Object` for both the matrix and `ArrayList` types. This is due to having a 2D array of mixed types, and limitations on converting between primitives and objects in Java. You could have `matrixA` be of type `int[]` and `rowHolder` have generic parameter `Integer` if you used a custom converter instead of [`ArrayList#toArray`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#toArray()).